# API testing script is having high failure on EC2 compared to that on local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, testing, amazon-ec2, web-api-testing

I have written a Python script for making a POST call and then a GET call. After that I am checking if the change has been reflected or not. I am running this script on my local machine and it is giving nearly 100% success rate but when I am running the same script the success rate falls down to around 53%.

By success I mean if the POST and GET call are done then out of them in how many calls the change has been reflected.

```
import requests
import time

access_token = ""
def set_support_setup_steps(api_url, payload, access_token):
    try:
        headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(access_token)
        }
        response = requests.post(api_url, json=payload, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raise exception for any error status codes (4xx or 5xx)

        data = response.json()  # Parse response JSON data
        return data

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print("Error occurred during API request:", e)
        return None

def fetch_support_setup_steps(api_url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(api_url)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raise exception for any error status codes (4xx or 5xx)

        data = response.json()  # Parse response JSON data
        support_setup_steps = data['payload']['supportSetupSteps']
        return support_setup_steps

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print("Error occurred during API request:", e)
        return None


api_url_fetch_support_setup_steps = 
api_url_set_support_setup_steps = 


payload = {
    "supportSetupSteps": True,
}
# Example loop to set and fetch supportSetupSteps
cnt = 0
successful_calls = 0
failures_calls = 0
N=100
while cnt < N:
    # Change the value of supportSetupSteps in each iteration
    support_setup_steps_value = cnt % 2 == 0  # Alternate between True and False
    payload['supportSetupSteps'] = support_setup_steps_value
    print("Iteration number: {}".format(cnt))
    cnt = cnt+1
    # Set supportSetupSteps
    data = set_support_setup_steps(api_url_set_support_setup_steps, payload, access_token)

    if not data:
        print("Failed to set supportSetupSteps to " + str(payload['supportSetupSteps']))
    else:
        # Fetch supportSetupSteps
        support_setup_steps = fetch_support_setup_steps(api_url_fetch_support_setup_steps)

        if support_setup_steps is not None:
            successful_calls = successful_calls + 1
            if support_setup_steps != support_setup_steps_value:
                failures_calls = failures_calls + 1
        else:
            print("Failed to fetch support_setup_steps")

    time.sleep(1)
file_path = r"/home/ubuntu/cache/new_file.txt"  # Specify the full path including the directory and filename

# Open the file in "write" mode using the 'w' mode flag
with open(file_path, "w") as file:
    file.write("Details\n")
    file.write("Total number of successful calls: ")
    file.write(str(successful_calls))
    file.write("\n")
    file.write("Number of times fetched data and set data Failed: ")
    file.write(str(failures_calls))
```

This is my script. Can someone tell what can be done to get the success rate on EC2 as that I am getting on my local machine.

Comment: Does your "set" code receive 200 responses when posting the values? If so, it might be the remote system that is having the problems. Do your "not set" errors occur in the `if not data` part, or in the `fetch != value` part?

Comment: I am checking for 200 responses when posting the values. 
"not set" error occurs in **if not data** part.

Comment: So which one is impacting the 'success' score? If the 'set' process is receiving a 200 response, but the 'fetch' process is saying the value wasn't stored, then it sounds like an error in the remote system. It shouldn't have sent a 200 if it didn't store the value.